# Работа Android с Wi-Fi

Tags: android

Подскажите как правильно работать с Wi-Fi (передавать, получать файлы внутри сети). В официальной документации не нашел информации на этот счет. Есть много сторонних ресурсов, но везде разная информация, а в некоторых местах противоречит друг другу.
Научился подключаться к серверу, но чувствуется что тут очень много подводных камней. Посоветуйте манулы на эту тему, можно как на русском,  так и на английском.